# Django filter Logging to slack channel

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a function to filter the error message that sent to Slack channel. I still want it to log in .log file just dont want it sent it out to Slack. This is what i have tried so far:

```
def contains_url(record):
   if 'abc' in record.request.path:
       return False
   return True


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[{levelname}] {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {'format': '[{levelname}] -- : {message}', 'style': '{',},
    },
    'filters': {
        'contains_url': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': contains_url,
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'log.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'slack_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['contains_url'],
            'class': 'django_slack.log.SlackExceptionHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['console','file','slack_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },

}
```

so basically, i would want all the error message from an url that contain 'abc' log to the `log.log` as usual but just not want it in slack channel. I added `slack_admins -> filters` but it didn't help. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Is `abc` in the path or in the domain name? If it's in the domain name, you might want to use `record.request.build_absolute_uri()` instead

Comment: @bdbd why it’s keep telling me that. There is no attribute request when it’s accessing record.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#id3), it says you need to add `django.request` as a logger to get the request from record

Comment: @bdbd Thanks for response. i have added it but still not working. please see my edit questions. I keep getting error `AttributeError: 'LogRecord' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: It's probably because `loggers['django']` (which doesn't add request) is still using `slack_admins` handler? Try to remove it

Comment: @bdbd But i still want to get other error sent to slack. except url that contains `abc`. If i remove `slack_admins`, it might not sent anything to slack. Do you think so ?

Comment: Just remove on `django` and not `django.request`. It should still be handled

Comment: @bdbd Thanks for your help. so  i did remove the `slack_admins` in `django` but however, nothing sent to slack anymore even other error. Which i dont want it to happen. whats wrong here ? i am trying different things now. feel like it getting close. please see my question for the code updated.

Comment: @bdbd i have a feeling that `django.request` not even kicking.

Comment: What does `os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')` return? Maybe try to debug if it does go through either `slack_admins` or `contains_url`.

Comment: @bdbd ok. so it got it working. please see my question update. Now, it only log to file and not sending it to slack which is great. However, the log that i got in the file is Error and Warning only. I want it to have full Debug message too. I already double check everything but still stuck on that. Sooo closeee...!!!

Comment: Can you show how you log your errors? Did you mean you want the whole traceback on errors, or also debug logs?

Comment: @bdbd correct. so i want the whole traceback on errors in the file but not sending to Slack.

Comment: So when a `DisallowedHost` get caught and the URL contains `abc`. It will not send to slack but whole traceback errors or debug logs need to be in the `file` handlers.

Comment: at this point, everything is working as i expected. Only last thing that i want is, the whole traceback on errors  (Debug) in the log file. instead of just a warning or error (only one line of error message)

Comment: In that case you need to use [`logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) or add the exception info in [`logger.debug`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)